# Is it possible to redirect a admin user to a specific component after login?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, administrator

Not too much else to add to the question really, I'm trying to redirect a specific user group to a specific area after they log in to the administrator back-end, but I'm not sure if this is possible.

While somewhat of a separate goal, I also want to hide the admin menu.

Comment: Have you tried looking on the Joomla Extensions Directory? Maybe this might help: http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/access-a-security/site-access/redirect-after-login

Comment: Preferably the solution would be free, at least at all if it's possible. I've been looking in various places including many Google searches.

Comment: Lodder, i was already create (and installed of course) a plugin (named '*RedireccionarAdministrativo*'), exactly as you said, but it doesn't work. First of all, the system respond: "Call to undefined method plgAuthenticationRedireccionarAdministrativo::onUserAuthenticate()" after login. Secon of all, i'v changed the name of the method to "onUserAuthenticate", runs, but do not redirect. Can you help me, please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @BENKENOBI - Please create a new question so other users can see it aswell. Thank you

Answer (score 10):

You could create a small plugin to perform the redirect. Here's something I've quickly mocked up:

```
class plgSystemMYPLUGIN extends JPlugin
{

    public function onUserAfterLogin()
    {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();

        if ($app->isAdmin()) 
        {
            $user   = JFactory::getUser();
            $groups = $user->get('groups');

            $groups_to_redirect = array('13', '10');

            if (in_array($groups[0], $groups_to_redirect))
            {
                $url = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_hellowworld');
                $app->redirect($url);
            }           
        }
    }

}
```

I've used `10` and `13` as example user group ID's, so you would have to change them to whatever suits your needs.

Please also note I haven't tested this, but hope it points you in the right direction

Comment: Works great!
Just a small addition, a user can belong to multiple groups. Moreover, the group array is indexed by key (Joomla 3.8+). Therefore, this would work better:
**if ( !empty(array_intersect($groups, $groups_to_redirect)) )**

Answer (score 1):

How about that extension?
I'd used it before when i needed to redirect users to specified direction :

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-access/redirect-on-login

Comment: This is an extremely big extension just to perform a simple redirect on admin login. Have you not found any *simple and small* alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Its Just short cut method in 3.x

Open Path in Joomla  plugins\authentication\cookie\cookie.php

In function onUserAfterLogin($options),

```
        $user   = JFactory::getUser();
        $groups = $user->get('groups');

            if(in_array(10, $groups)) 
            {
             $url = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_students');
             $this->app->redirect($url);
            }
```

Comment: Changing the core files of any updateable system is NOT recommended.

Comment: Its just work around method.  Invoke function call.